# PDF generated by TcPDF (PHP) won't open in Adobe Acrobat XI

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, adobe-reader

I'm able to generate a PDF file using TcPDF ver 6.0.44. The file opens fine in the browser, and 3rd party PDF readers  but will not open in Adobe Reader XI. I keep getting a the error message 'file type is not supported or the file is damaged'.

What's going on here? Here's the code I wrote:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>';
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->Output('htmlout.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Very strange.  What headers do you use to create the PDF?  Like what are the starting commands .. and what do you use to output/save it?

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis I've updated the original post with the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

In your test file if you are using images , and some of your images are missing icc profile, adobe acrobat doesnt recognize this and cause the problem you are facing.